# Memory Leak while using NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have seen many questions/answers on memory leaks in NSDateFormatter, but none seems to help me determine what is causing memory to leak in my app. Here is my code:

```
- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    {
        items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        buffer = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        lastFromDate = @"";
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)presentingDatesFrom:(NSDate *)fromDate to:(NSDate *)toDate delegate:(id<KalDataSourceCallbacks>)delegate
{ 
    [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [format setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [NSString stringWithString:[format stringFromDate:fromDate]];
    NSString *stringToDate = [NSString stringWithString:[format stringFromDate:toDate]];

    NSLog(@"From date: %@, To date: %@", stringFromDate, stringToDate); 

    [self didDatesChange:stringFromDate];

    if (dataReady) {
        [callback loadedDataSource:self];
        return;
    }
    callback = delegate;
    [self retrieveEventData:stringFromDate to:stringToDate];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [items release];
    [events release];
    [buffer release];
    [lastFromDate release];
    [format release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When I run "Profile" -> "Leaks", I get a memory leak every time the function is called on line

```
NSString *stringFromDate = [NSString stringWithString:[format stringFromDate:fromDate]];
```

Can someone explain what might be going on?
thanks, mike

Comment: please post didDatesChange: and retrieveEventData:to:.  since there are no obvious leaks in the code in your question, my guess is an unbalanced retain inside of one of those methods.

Comment: why would Instruments point me to the line where NSDate is formatted if the leaks were in either one of those functions?

Answer (score 2):

FYI you can change this:

```
 NSString *stringFromDate = [NSString stringWithString:[format stringFromDate:fromDate]];
```

to this:

```
 NSString *stringFromDate = [format stringFromDate:fromDate];
```

stringWithString should return an autoreleased NSString though so I don't believe that is the source of your leak. It looks like there is no leak in your code to me.

Answer (score 2):

you just use bellow method for get string from date its work properly......

```
-(NSString *)StringFromDate:(NSDate *)DateLocal{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:DateLocal];  
    NSLog(@"Date is HERE  =====>> %@",dateString);
    return dateString;
}
```

after when you want to get date string just use like bellow....

```
NSString *stringFromDate = [self stringFromDate:fromDate]];
[stringfromdate retain];
NSString *stringToDate = [self stringFromDate:toDate]];
[stringTodate retain];
```

and above -(NSString *)StringFromDate:(NSDate *)DateLocal method is must be define in your viewcontroller.m file....
Its work fine....

Comment: you need to release the NSDateFormatter you alloc in the method.

Comment: yes i know but now i just define the code which is useful to user with its problem, i use dateFormat globaly in my app.....although Thanx... :-)

Comment: I have NSDateFormatter defined globally, because I don't want to create new one every single time this function is being called. This would recreate it every single time, correct? Is there any advantages/disadvantages to that?

Comment: @ParasJoshi I tried you solution, still got memory leak on line where stringFromDate:DateLocal is being called.